# Is there any ojAlgo solver for when the condition number is large and the matrix is symmetric and indefinite?

Tags: java, solver, linear-equation, ojalgo, indefinite

I use ojAlgo to solve a system of linear equations.
In one case I get a RecoverableCondition exception. Probably because matrix is ill-conditioned, the condition number is about 1e15.

I use ojAlgo to solve it as seen in the code below. It usually works, but not in this case.

Is there any other solver I could use for a symmetric indefinite (ill-conditioned) matrix?

The present failing size is 18x18 but later 1000x1000 might be needed. Since its part of a iterative algorithm the accuracy is not super important.

```
         SolverTask<Double> equationSolver = SolverTask.PRIMITIVE.make(KKT, rhs.negate());
         MatrixStore<Double> deltaX = null;
         try {
            deltaX = equationSolver.solve(KKT, rhs.negate());
         } catch (RecoverableCondition ex) {
            int i = 0;
         }
```

I tried to reproduce this in a self contained example but failed, because there it works. Maybe I do not get exactly the same matrix down to the last bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, that method would use a Cholesky decomposition as the solver.

If here's a problem then try to pick another decomposition by instantiating a suitable alternative directly. An SVD can usually handle anything, but that would be very expensive. Perhaps QR can be ok.

```
QR<Double> qr = QR.PRIMITIVE.make(templateBody);
qr.decompose(body);
qr.getSolution(rhs,x);
```

This way you can reuse the decomposition instance as well as the solution vector `x`.

Another alternative is to precondition the body/KKT matrix. Perhaps add a small diagonal - just enough to make the Cholesky decomposition solvable.

```
if (!cholesky.isSolvable()) {
    // Fix that
}
```

Or perhaps try something in the `org.ojalgo.matrix.task.iterative` package.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!
I will try another decomposition, and/or preconditioning.
 
According to the Templates book beginning of section 2.3.2
http://www.netlib.org/templates/templates.pdf
CG might get into problem for symmetric indefinite systems.
For Jacobi and Gauss–Seidel method convergence is only guaranteed for a limited class of matrices.

Comment: I do not find MINRES (symmetric indefinite) or GMRES (general indefinite) in ojAlgo.
Should they be added to ojAlgo in a identical way to CG?
Maybe like 
http://netlib3.cs.utk.edu/templates/matlab/gmres.m
https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/minres/

On the last page of the Templates book there is a flow chart for selecting an iterative method. It indicate CG might work "anyway".

Cheers,
Magnus

Comment: That would be great contributions.